# Currency server security

Tags: security, currency, trading

I have a theoretical question. Let's say I created a digital currency (like BitCoin). My currency is running on private servers, so every user has a server for a their account. To send money from user A to user B, user A's server contact user B's server and gives the money. **How can I prevent user A's server from creating money (with creating money I mean that the server doesn't subtract from user A's account)?**

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to limit the total amount of coins that can exist and give each coin a serial number of some kind. You will need a protocol that can be used between the servers to detect if two servers claims to "own" the same coin at the same time. A server that claims to own a coin must be able to prove this by presenting the transaction where it got the coin. That way, each coin can be backtracked trough all transactions to its origin. Rouge servers that claims to own a coin that cannot be backtracked must be excluded by the community.

PS: This strategy is somewhat similar to what bitcoin does.

Comment: But what if the last server which created the coin is saying that it was another server who created it?